# Can't wrap text in Animated.View - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am newbie in react native animations. I am using react native animated to move menu right and push all content to right without cutting text, but as you see it is not wrapping.

[image]

I have already tried these solutions:

- Using `flexShrink` for the `Text` component
- `flex: 1` and `flexWrap` to the parent `View` element
  but nothing has worked, could somebody give me some advice?

  ```
  `<Animated.View style={boxValue.getLayout()}>

  <Text style={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur
       dapibus massa eu quam porttitor, id suscipit felis volutpat. Duis
       tempus turpis
  </Text>
   </Animated.View>`
  ```

Comment: Could you please share some more of your code? How is the menu rendered? How is boxValue.getLayout() pushing the view to the right?

Comment: https://github.com/elencho/custom-drawers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is entirely possible using the [Animated API](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations). You can wrap the text component in a `Animated.View` that is shifted to right using an `Animated.Value` combined with styling the text with `flexWrap: 'wrap'`. That seems to be what you were going for, but perhaps you are not updating the width of the text container? Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@joachimwedin/intelligent-orange) showing the general idea in action.